# Can someone confirm the standard contract for XAUUSD?

Tags: gold

Am getting nothing but click bait these days that is purposely vague. Broker omits it on the dash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as Standard Contract.

Every exchange and CFD broker has its own specification with regards to underlying, multiplier, margin requirement, settlement etc.

If you want a representative example:

https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold_contract_specifications.html

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought. I finally found it on the broker. Had even traded this before.